# Transfer Oracle columns to an array

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

My problem is I have a large number of similarly defined columns with slightly different names in a table and I want to test their values in a record without using their names. I could use their names and a long string of elsif statements but I prefer not to. Unpivot needs the names and collections seems to need them as well. I tried selecting * into a varray but oracle raised an error.

I tried selecting * into a varray but oracle raised an error. I have tried defining a record type and selecting into a variable based on that but I can only access the values by name.
If I can find a way of getting all the columns into an array it would solve the problem. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output, Also share the full query you tried

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot be bothered to type all the column names then query the data dictionary and generate the SQL with all the names:

```sql
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM "' || table_name || '" UNPIVOT (value FOR name IN (' || LISTAGG('"'||column_name||'"', ',') ||'))' AS sql
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  table_name ='TABLE_NAME'
GROUP BY table_name;
```

Which, if you have created the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (a, b, c, d, e) AS
SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output of the query is:

| SQL |
| --- |
| SELECT * FROM "TABLE_NAME" UNPIVOT (value FOR name IN ("A","B","C","D","E")) |

Then copy-paste the generated query and execute it, which outputs:

| NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 4 |
| E | 5 |

And all the values are in columns with the associated columns they are in and you can just work on two columns named `NAME` and `VALUE` (which could be aggregated into a collection if you require).

---

If you want to not unpivot some columns then just exclude those from the aggregation:

```sql
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM "' || table_name || '" UNPIVOT (value FOR name IN (' || LISTAGG('"'||column_name||'"', ',') ||'))' AS sql
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  table_name ='TABLE_NAME'
AND    column_name NOT IN ('A', 'C')
GROUP BY table_name;
```

Then the generated query is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "TABLE_NAME" UNPIVOT (value FOR name IN ("B","D","E"))
```

Which outputs (without unpivoting A or C):

| A | C | NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | B | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | D | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | E | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tMQNaDa_)